# Serializing only checked cheboxes and sending them through $.get

Tags: jquery, html, dom

have been at this for a while now, and can't seem to get it to work, I either need to do it via POST or GET, however I keep getting stuck, current code I have is

```
<script>

        $('#RequestSupport2').submit(function() {
            var values = {};
            $("#RequestSupport2 :checked").each(function(key, value) {
             // alert("key"+key+"value = " + $(this).val());
                values[this.name] = $(this).val();

            });
            var values2 = $(values).serialize();

            $.post("URL", { name: values2}, function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
            return false;

        });
</script>
```

As GET didn't work as there were too many check boxes and string just became too long, anyone could help getting this to work with either GET or POST? and post through only checked elements,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the space `#RequestSupport2` and `:checked`

```
$("#RequestSupport2:checked").each(function(key, value) {
```